# Can Mathematica/WolframAlpha do a Fourier transform for f instead of ω?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

When Mathematica/WolframAlpha calculates the Fourier Transform, it calculates it using the angular frequency. How do I make the Fourier transforms Mathematica/WolframAlpha to match the following table?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/fourier-theorems/) by [@John Cook](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/247/john-d-cook) for Fourier theorems under various conventions.